# error: control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c, cs50, linear-search

Please someone can explain me what's wrong why am I getting this error:

```
error: control may reach end of non-void function
```

I am trying to make a function `linearsearch()` taking a key and a table returning the index of an element if found.
It's confusing; I am a beginner and taking cs50 online course; I've never had this error before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int linearsearch(int key, int array[]);

int main(int argc , string argv[])
{ 
    int key = 0;
    int table[]={2,4,5,1,3};

    printf("%i is found in index %i\n",key,linearsearch(1,table));
}

int linearsearch(int key, int array[])
{
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
        if(array[i] == key)
        {
             return i;
        }    
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no applicable error for not returning a value from a no-void function here. There *might* be an (incorrect) compiler *warning* though. The glaringly obvious error in your code is elsewhere.

Comment: Possibly the error refers to not returning a value from `main` (and the compiler is in pre-C99 mode).  The error message should have a line number associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last for loop you're returning something from the function either way, so there shouldn't be any problem (except that your algorithm is wrong: it shouldn't return immediately if not found).

The problem is: the compiler doesn't necessarily see that you're returning whatever the data is. It just sees that don't end your routine by returning something.

Most compilers can figure out simple cases like:

```
   if (x) return 0; else return 1;
  // not returning anything in the main branch but ok as it's seen as unreachable
}
```

but in your case, you have a `for` loop wrapping the return instructions. Compilers are not control flow analysers. They do basic things, but certainly not formal execution. So sometimes they issue a warning where it's "OK" from your point of view.

Anyway, your algorithm is incorrect as mentioned earlier. Fix it by returning -1 only when the loop ends without finding anything.

In that case, you fix your bug AND the warning. So you see the warning was rightly detecting something fishy in your code.

Fixed code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == key)
    {
         // found return & exit loop
         return i;
    }    
}
// not found, end of loop: return -1
return -1;
```

Comment: thanks a lot I get it I don't know how i was so blind I made this error now it's working reaaly you saved my life